# Does the socket.io client have to exist in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, requirejs, browserify

I'm using a module (say `M`), created by browserify, which includes as a dependency the socket.io client. `M` is being used inside an AMD application. Inside said app, when `M` issues a connect call to the socket client, and when the chosen transport is jsonp-polling, attempting to execute the jsonp callback throws a `ReferenceError: io is undefined`. This makes perfect sense to me, as `io` is not global, instead, it is wrapped inside module `M`.

So my question is, does `io` **have** to exist in the global scope?  Is there a way to make this work whereby the callback array can be accessed without adding `io` to the global scope?

**Disclaimer** - I appreciate I haven't provided any example code, but I'm struggling to form a suitable mock example that'll be easy to implement and run. If the question really doesn't make any sense then please let me know and I'll see if I can put something together, but if anyone thinks they can answer it, or point me in the right direction without seeing any code, please do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't have to be in the global namespace, but it takes some work and you can't use the pre-built file found in the root of the github project.

You should build the the `socketio-client` project from source. Only problem is that the project is built using `component.js`, a simple client side package manager created by the great TJ Hallowaychuck. The problem you will run into is that when a component is built with `component(1)`, it ships with its own implementation of the `require()` function which competes in the global namespace with browserify's own implementation.

All is not lost, however! Transforms to the rescue...

https://github.com/eugeneware/decomponentify

Using this transform, you can consume the module built by `component(1)` and `require()` it within browserify like any other browserify enabled module. Read the docs for usage.

Yes, I too wait for the day for standardization in client side package management.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get into that and see how it goes. I'll mark this as the answer but there may well be more questions that arise. Cheers.